# Scroll down in navigation menu using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

I've a navigation menu in my application, I wanna to click on an item inside but I should scroll down in navigation menu to reach the item.
Espresso recorder didn't detect the scroll/swipe action I made on the screen, it just detected the click action on the item.

```
ViewInteraction appCompatCheckedTextView = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.resourceid), withText("Settings"), isDisplayed()));
        appCompatCheckedTextView.perform(click());
```

How can I implement the swipe / scroll action in navigation menu?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by navigation menu? A navigation drawer that swipes in from the side? (like this? https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/navigation-drawer.html)

Comment: Exactly ,, That's what I mean and I solved the problem by adding this code above the recorded one ..

ViewInteraction X = onView(withId(R.id.design_navigation_view),perform(swipeup()));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Recorder to Swipe/Scroll. It is not supported on Android Studio recorder as yet. Please follow this link for future updates:

[Weblink: Issue 235615 in android Studio](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37137246)

Comment: Yeah, we should add it ourselves .. I resolved it with swipeup()

Answer (score 4):

I solved it down by getting the resource id of navigation drawer and swipe up inside it.

```
ViewInteraction viewInteraction = onView(withId(R.id.nav_bar)).perform(swipeUp());
```

I added it before the above code and it worked.

Comment: what is nav_bar ?

Comment: @NullByte08 `R.id.nav_bar` should be the resource_id of the navigation menu in your application.